# WCF trace log override old messages

Tags: c#, wcf

I would like to limit the number of log files that the WCF trace is writing.
in order to so, I used the maxMessagesToLog attribute.
What happen when it gets to its limit, let say 2000 messages?
does it stop writing or it override the old messages?

I would like to override the old message. How i'm doing it? 
What is the best practice?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement a circular trace listener to reach what you want. With it you can set the maximum file size the trace log can get. After reaching it the old entries get overridden.

See this sample and explanation on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa395205.aspx)